# Java and Random method

Tags: java, random

I want to create something like Flashing Light with *.
for being Flashing I decided to use "For" that Repeats 5000 times , also I want the Max * in each line be 25 but my code is not working . Does any body have any suggestion ? my code is

```
 void test() {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        rnd = nextInt(25);

        for (int j = 0; j < rnd; j++) {
            System.out.print(" * ");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What it means "flashing" ?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. For one thing, your code has obvious syntax errors. You could start by searching how to use Random class in Java.

Comment: @Zircon I meant in output shows me random stars in each line , if it  happens for 5000 times for example , it'll be flashing.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO  I meant in output shows me random stars in each line , if it happens for 5000 times for example , it'll be flashing

Comment: @Grayson tnx for your solution !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {

    int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(25);

    for (int j = 0; j < rndInt; j++) {
        System.out.print(" * ");

    }
    System.out.println();  // newline

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of `nextInt` is not done right. Assign `rnd.nextInt(25)` to a seperate `int` variable, like so:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {

    int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(25);

    for (int j = 0; j < rndInt; j++) {
        System.out.print(" * ");

    }

}
```